# dspace I want different items for each collection

Tags: collections, items, dspace

I want to assign different items for each collection. the forms i make in input-forms.xml but I dont know where I can relate to items created collections.
I think the option is the tag collection-handle = "name" but I dont know how that is related with collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a collection handle that maps a different set of fields to different collections.

I am a bit confused by your question.  If you navigate to a collection in your DSpace website, the handle for that collection will be visible in the URL.

Here is an example of how we have customized our input forms for a specific collection.

```
<input-forms>

 <form-map>
   <name-map collection-handle="10822/000999" form-name="faculty" />
 </form-map>
 <form-map>
   <name-map collection-handle="default" form-name="traditional" />
 </form-map>

 <form-definitions>

   <form name="traditio l">
   ...
   </form>

   <form name="faculty">
   ...
   </form>

 </form-definitions>

</input-forms>
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. It was just what I was looking for, this relation
Thank you very much